# Problems with 2-dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class noise 
{
    public static float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, float scale)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[mapWidth, mapHeight];

        if (scale <= 0)
        {
            scale = 0.0001f;
        }
        for(int y = 0; y<mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; y < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                float sampleX = x/(mapWidth * scale);
                float sampleY = y/(mapHeight * scale);

                float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise(sampleX, sampleY);
                
                noiseMap[x, y] = perlinValue;
                Debug.Log(noiseMap.GetLength(0));
                Debug.Log(noiseMap.GetLength(1));
            }
        }
        return noiseMap;
    }
}
```

Above is the code that is giving me the error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>
> noise.GenerateNoiseMap (Int32 mapWidth, Int32 mapHeight, Single scale) (at
>
> Assets/Scripts/MapGeneration/noise.cs:24)

I'm not entirely familiar with how arrays work in C# (or at all) but my teachers says that the most common issue with arrays that yield an IndexOutOfRange error is that I'm starting at 1 instead of index 0. I've tried to fix this but that doesn't seem to be the problem in this section of code.

I am attempting to generate a Perlin noise map for my custom game.

What is throwing the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for (int x = 0; y < mapWidth; x++)

I think that middle value should be X, I've never seen a for loop written with a different variable, I can't see how that would work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int x = 0; y < mapWidth; x++)
```

it should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
```